# How parse Sql Script with dapper? (SET PARSEONLY ON + Dapper)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parsing, dapper

I want to check & parse sql script so I searched for that and I found something like this

```
SET PARSEONLY ON 
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Categories]  --Query To Parse
```

I use dapper, so I write method like this

```
 public bool IsValidSqlScript(string sqlScript)
    {
        using (SQLConnection)
        {
            using (SQLTransaction)
            {
                var status = SQLConnection.Execute("SET PARSEONLY ON " + sqlScript);
                // OR
                // var status = SQLConnection.Query("SET PARSEONLY ON " + sqlScript);
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
```

How I can get status and if exists any errors get error`s list also ???

```
SET PARSEONLY ON
SELECT * FR OM [dbo].[Categories]  --Query To Parse

>>> false
>>> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near 'FR'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you've got an issue with your status variable.  You declare it inside your SQLTransaction using statement and then you try and return it outside of that scope.

You'll want to use a try/catch block to execute your query, that way you'll know when the `sqlScript` is valid or not.  If you enter the catch block, it's invalid, and if you don't then it is valid.

The code should look similar to the following...

```
public bool IsValidSqlScript(string sqlScript)
{
    bool status;

    try
    {
        using (SQLConnection)
        {
            using (SQLTransaction)
            {
                SQLConnection.Execute("SET PARSEONLY ON " + sqlScript);                    
            }
        }
        status = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        status = false;
    )

    return status;
}
```